# How to configure vim so that line number can show/hide by F10?

Tags: vim

Anyone knows how to configure vim so that line number can show/hide by F10?

Now I'm typing `set nu/nonu`,which is not convenient...

Answer (score 5):

`map <F10> :set number!` <- Should do the trick (AFAIK, the ! at the end makes it a toggle, instead of an always-on).

EDIT: Apologies, I forgot an important note (which you may have already known, but it was inconsiderate of me to forget): To make this persistent, add this line to your `.vimrc` file.

Take a look at [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29) for reference, and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762515/vim-remap-key-to-toggle-line-numbering) for more.